# RDP data encryption error

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp

I got "Because of an error in data encryption, this session will end. Please try to connecting to remote computer again."

On metal is hyperv 2008 R2 instaled. As virutal machine is W server 2008 R2 Standard.

I have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TermService\Parameters certs deleted,
and I have Large Send Offload v2 (IPv4) disabled in Lan settings.

I am trying to connect from Windows XP Home edition with SP3.

On XP got Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client update installed.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20609.

Also have RDP klient 7.0 Credential Provider Fix (KB951608) applied.
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/whsvailbeta/thread/b35c5d4f-b5d4-451e-b878-706229c303c5

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 1):

Check that duplex/speed is ok on the whole chain.

On the client and server, launch a cmd, and do `netstat -e` Check that there is no error on it.

I would also check date/time to be ok.

Comment: all mentioned tested, no error...

Comment: I have the same problem but with windows 10 on the RDP host and the client. The netstat -e command has 2 error in the send column.  How can I fix it?

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles :  check network cable, and check also for errors on switch port where you are connected

Comment: @MathieuChateau no.. nothing... The connection is Wifi, the port of the router is by the ISP directly. This error is with all RDP. I formated the PC and try with Original Windows O.S. the result is the same

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles ensure remote desktop is enabled, and firewall on Windows accept incoming rdp connection. Also ensure that it's not your isp router which block traffic. Best way would be to have both computer using ethernet